# Two unknown variables and two known: basic math question

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

My question is very basic so I expect answers pretty quickly. Sorry if I sound stupid, I'm not very great at math.

So I have this:
$$xz = y$$

I have the value of $x$, and I have the value of $y$. I can easily calculate $z$:

$$z = \frac{y}x$$

There's one unknown variable and two known.

But in my *real* question, there's something more:
$$(xz) + v = y$$

Again, I have the value of $x$ and $y$. I need the find the value of $v$ and $z$.

**If there are many possible values for $v$ and $z$, I need a way to find one possible pair of values.

Please help me!

Comment: "I expect answers pretty quickly"... Being in a hurry is never good... and we are not good at obeying to such a pressure even for elementary questions.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yeah. I'm sorry, I'm new to this stackexchange. I've read up now. Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=0$, then you can recover the value of $v$ easily.

In general, once you determine the value of $z$, you can  recover $v$.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an example and ellaborate more. I didn't understand anything.

Comment: Please try to let $z=0$ and observe what is $v$ first.

Comment: If z is zero, then v will be y

Comment: yup, you have found a pair of them. congratulations, you have achieved your goal. Now what if you let $z=1$, can you solve for $v$?

Comment: Wait... I understood! Thank you so much :)

Comment: +1 and accepted. What else can I do to thank you?

Comment: continue learning and explore.

Comment: Thank you so much. I surely will :)